# how can I detect com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0 as a preprocessor macro?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, llvm

I have some code that doesn't compile with the llvm compiler that is the default in xcode4.5, how can I #ifdef out that code?

thank

Comment: It helps if you show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you fix your code, you're probably relying on undefined/unspecified behavior that just happens to be accepted by other compilers.  Post your code and the error messages, and we can help you fix it.

But if you insist on just treating the symptoms and not the cause, you can figure out what preprocessor macros the compiler defines by running this command from the terminal:

```
# This should work for any GCC, LLVM, or Clang variant
/path/to/your/compiler -dM -E -xc /dev/null | sort
```

From that output, look for macros indicating the specific compiler and version.